# mod-rewrite infinite recursion

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have the following problem with apaches mod-rewrite (it's probably a simple one, but I'm just not getting it ...)

I want my URL paths to start with a two-letter part (country code), like

```
http://www.example.com/se/
```

Whenever an URL doesn't match this pattern, I want my `.htaccess` to do a redirect to a fixed starting address like the above `http://www.example.com/se/`.

I also need to redirect URLs that do not end in a trailing slash (i.e. `http://www.example.com/se` should also be redirected ...)

I've put the following lines in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^/[a-z]{2}/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ se/ [R,L]
```

But this results in an infinite recursion since a request `http://www.example.com/se/` is also redirected. I do not get, why the `RewriteCond` becomes true in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking if your query string (this is all the stuff *after* the `?` in the URL) doesn't start with `/[a-z]{2}/`. And in your example, it doesn't. Thus, after the redirect, the query string **still** doesn't start with that, thus you get redirected again, to the same URL. And then again, and again.

I think what you're looking for is `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[a-z]{2}/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ se/ [R,L]
```